# Visual Studio auto gen files create GIT conflict

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to merge a branch into the master repo on GIT, but Visual Studio is giving me this error:
[image]

I have moved the file it is referring to in my file location, but it just autogenerates a new one. I have also stashed the file as below, but I am still getting the error when I try to merge the branch into the Master.
[image]

This is the first time I've attempted to use GIT with Visual Studio and I cannot seem to find a solution to what I'm seeing. I have looked through a lot of the Visual Studio issues on stackoverflow, but I haven't seen a solution for this. If I have missed it, please let me know the right forum and I will go there.

Thanks for any advice you can give!